# EF Power Tools Beta 2 Generate Views gives error: "a constructible type deriving from dbcontext could not be found in the selected file"

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I get this error when running Generate Views for a file that contains 1 class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public MyDbContext() { ... }

    public MyDbContext(string connectionString) { ... }

    // more constructors

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { ... }
}
```

I am using EF 4.3.1.0, VS 10, and Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2 0.6.0.0. This is my first time installing these tools, so I don't think it's the issue mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx).

How can I get around this issue and generate precompiled views for my DbContext?

Comment: Im getting the same error with EF5.0.  Did you find the issue ?

Comment: Restarting VisualStudio 2012 justed worked for me.